# Saving vectors of different lengths in a matrix/data frame

Tags: r

I have a numeric called area of length 166860. This consists of 412 different elements, most of length 405 and some of length 809. I have their start and end ids.

My goal is to extract them and put them in a matrix/data frame with 412 columns

Right now, I'm trying this code:

```
m = matrix(NA,ncol=412, nrow=809)
for (j in 1:412){
temp.start = start.ids[j]
temp.end = end.ids[j]
m[,j] = area[temp.start:temp.end]
}
```

But I just end up with this error message:

"Error in m[, j] = area[temp.start:temp.end] : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"

Comment: Typically you'd put them into a list (which allows it's elements to be of different lengths) or create a long-format data.frame with an id column and a values column. I would do the latter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a quite easy approach:

Example data:

```
area <- c(1:4, 1:5, 1:6, 1:3)
# [1] 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3

start.ids <- which(area == 1)
# [1]  1  5 10 16

end.ids <- c(which(area == 1)[-1] - 1, length(area))
# [1]  4  9 15 18
```

Create a list with one-row matrices:

```
mats <- mapply(function(x, y) t(area[seq(x, y)]), start.ids, end.ids)
# [[1]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    2    3    4
# 
# [[2]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    2    3    4    5
#
# [[3]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6
# 
# [[4]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    2    3
```

Use the function `rbind.fill.matrix` from the `plyr` package to create the matrix and transpose it (`t`):

```
library(plyr)
m <- t(rbind.fill.matrix(mats))
#    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# 1    1    1    1    1
# 2    2    2    2    2
# 3    3    3    3    3
# 4    4    4    4   NA
# 5   NA    5    5   NA
# 6   NA   NA    6   NA
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the column length to be 412, and matrices cannot be flexible/variable in their length.  This means the value you assign to the columns must either have a length of 412 or something less that can fill into a length of 412.  From the manual on ?matrix:

> If there are too few elements in data to fill the matrix, then the elements in data are recycled. If data has length zero, NA of an appropriate type is used for atomic vectors (0 for raw vectors) and NULL for lists.

As another commenter said, you may have intended to assign to the rows in which case m[j, ] is the way to do that, but you have to then pad the value you are assigning with NA or allow NA's to be filled so the value being assigned is always of length 809.

```
m = matrix(NA,ncol=412, nrow=809)
for (j in 1:412){
  temp.start = start.ids[j]
  temp.end = end.ids[j]
  val <- area[temp.start:temp.end]
  m[j, ] = c(val, rep(NA, 809 - length(val)))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this? I've manufactured some sample data:

```
#here are the random sets of numbers - length either 408 or 809
nums<-lapply(1:412,function(x)runif(sample(c(408,809),1)))

#this represents your numeric (one list of all the numbers)
nums.vec<-unlist(nums)

#get data about the series (which you have)
nums.lengths<-sapply(nums,function(x)length(x)) 
nums.starts<-cumsum(c(1,nums.lengths[-1]))
nums.ends<-nums.starts+nums.lengths-1


new.vec<-unlist(lapply(1:412,function(x){
    v<-nums.vec[nums.starts[x]:nums.ends[x]]
    c(v,rep(0,(809-length(v))))
}))

matrix(new.vec,ncol=412)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
m[j,] = area[temp.start:temp.end]
```

?

Edit:

```
  a <- area[temp.start:temp.end]
  m[1:length(a),j] <- a
```

Comment: Returns the same error message unfortunately

"Error in m[j, ] = area[temp.start:temp.end] : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"

Comment: @user2846211 yea that was stupid. Got a wrong idea. What about the edit?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe others have better answers. As I see it, you have two options:

1. Change m[,j] to m[1:length(area[temp.start:temp.end]),j] and then you will not get an error    but you would have some NA's left.
2. Use a list of matrices instead, so you would get different dimensions for each matrix.

Comment: I tried the latter option and I still got this error:

"Error in m[length(area[temp.start:temp.end]), j] = area[temp.start:temp.end] : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"

Comment: OK, I edited my comment, sorry. Other people suggestion not to use matrix seems more reasonable to me too.