# R: Can you save a file and then append to it by column?

Tags: r, append

I am familiar with appending data to a saved file (.txt, .csv) whereby the new data are added to the next row in the file, but is it possible to do this by column with R?

ETA:
I have vectors of varying lengths that I would like to save in a table.

```
element1 <- c("appple", "banana", "coconut")
element2 <- c("eggplant")
element3 <- c("fox", "giraffe")
```

Currently, I have done the following:

```
matrix1 <- matrix(nrow=1, c("Fruits", length(element1), element1))
matrix2 <- matrix(nrow=1, c("Vegetables", length(element2), element2))
matrix3 <- matrix(nrow=1, c("Animals", length(element3), element3))

write.table(matrix1, "table.txt", row.names=F, col.names=F, quote=F, sep="\t")
write.table(matrix2, "table.txt", row.names=F, col.names=F, quote=F, sep="\t", append=T)
write.table(matrix3, "table.txt", row.names=F, col.names=F, quote=F, sep="\t", append=T)
```

This gives me a table like so:

```
Fruits      3    appple    banana    cococnut
Vegetables  1    eggplant
Animals     2    fox       giraffe
```

However, with my real data, it would be easier to view the table transposed and save it to a .txt file:

```
Fruits    Vegetables    Animals
3         1             2
apple     eggplant      fox
banana                  giraffe
coconut
```

Suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: I believe that the core R write functions wrap C functions which do not support this functionality.

Comment: No. Not with R, or any other language. You can't write to the middle of a file without re-writing everything after it.

Comment: I mean, you can add columns wherever you'd like to an object _within_ `R`. Then save/load to your heart's content...

Comment: My issue is I have 12 elements of different lengths that I want to combine in a table. It would be easier to view the output as 12 columns instead of 12 rows, but since I can't have a data frame with columns of different lengths, I can't my add my columns within R. Though I guess I can just fill in the extra spaces with NAs or 0s.

Comment: @hmg sounds like you want a list. If you edit your question giving a [reproducible example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) it will be much easier to help you.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand the issue. Do you want to view the table like that in R? Or do you want to save it like that in a text file that you view in another software afterwards?

Comment: Also, does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21258584/saving-vectors-of-different-lengths-in-a-matrix-data-frame

Comment: I would like the save it like that in a text file for further analysis with other software, ideally without NAs.
The `rbind.fill.matrix` command looks handy--thanks for that