# Means across vectors of different lengths

Tags: r, mean, data-manipulation

I have 5 vectors of different lengths

```
a <- c(1) #with length of 1
b <- c(4.4,3.5) #length 2
c <- c(5.6,7.8,6.0) #length 3
d <- c(0.8,6.9,8.8,5.8) #length 4
e <- c(1.8,2.5,2.3,6.5,1.1) #length is 5
```

I am trying to get the mean of elements across all vectors:

```
 #since there are 5 values available for 1st element
 a[1]+b[1]+c[1]+d[1]+e[1] / 5 

 #since there are 4 values available for 2nd element
 b[2]+c[2]+d[2]+e[2] / 4 

#next divide by 3 and 2...1
c[3]+d[3]+e[3] / 3 and so on...
```

I need the mean of these values in another array so that I can do further processing of the data.

Comment: You could store the vectors in a matrix (like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21258584/saving-vectors-of-different-lengths-in-a-matrix-data-frame) and then take `rowMeans()` with `na.rm = TRUE`

Comment: Your data is already a list of time series and not a list of vectors. You should have stated so. Also. Can you include `class(b)` and `class(c)`

Comment: Try reading this: [xyproblem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: sorry @onyambu. The class of b,c,d are all lists

Comment: But in your question here, `class(a)` is numeric ie `class(c(1))` is nmeric. Do you now see why the solutions given will not work?

Comment: create a fake a, b, c, d that resembles your data and share those. You do not have to share the original 1,b,c that you have

Comment: @onyambu I have updated fake data

Comment: use `dput(x)` to include your data. Your data is not reproducible. ie run `dput(list(a, b, c, d, e)))` copy the output and paste it in your question. Simply put. Close this question by accepting any of the given solutions while maintaining the original question and then open a new one with the data

Comment: @onyambu I have created a new question. If you know how to do it. Can you please check

Comment: Put the link here

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let

```
l <- list(a, b, c, d, e)
```

then do:

```
tapply(unlist(l), sequence(lengths(l)), mean)
    1     2     3     4     5 
2.720 5.175 5.700 6.150 1.100
```

Another approach:

```
rowMeans(sapply(l, `length<-`, max(lengths(l))), na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 2.720 5.175 5.700 6.150 1.100
```

---

```
colMeans(plyr::rbind.fill.matrix(sapply(l, t)), na.rm = TRUE)
    1     2     3     4     5 
2.720 5.175 5.700 6.150 1.100
```

Answer (score 12):

With `data.table::transpose`:

```r
l <- list(a, b, c, d, e)
sapply(data.table::transpose(l), mean, na.rm = TRUE)
# [1] 2.720 5.175 5.700 6.150 1.100
```

Answer (score 9):

**1)** Create a list of the vectors and convert each to a ts object.  Then use cbind to create a multivariate ts object with each column corresponding to one of the original vectors.  Then use rowMeans on that.

```
nms <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
L <- mget(nms)
rowMeans(do.call("cbind", lapply(L, ts)), na.rm = TRUE)
## [1] 2.720 5.175 5.700 6.150 1.100
```

Check

```
(a[1] + b[1] + c[1] + d[1] + e[1]) / 5
## [1] 2.72

( b[2]+c[2]+d[2]+e[2]) / 4 
## [1] 5.175
```

**2)** Another approach using L from above is to use sapply:

```
n <- max(lengths(L))
sapply(1:n, function(i) mean(c(a[i], b[i], c[i], d[i], e[i]), na.rm = TRUE))
## [1] 2.720 5.175 5.700 6.150 1.100
```

**3)** or use sapply like this where L and n are from above:

```
rowMeans(sapply(L, `[`, 1:n), na.rm = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 5):

Another method that put your vectors into a list, then add `NA` to the vectors to make them equal length. Finally do a `rowMeans` on them.

```
mylist <- list(a, b, c, d ,e)
max_L <- max(lengths(mylist))

rowMeans(sapply(mylist, \(x) c(x, rep(NA, max_L - length(x)))), na.rm = T)
[1] 2.720 5.175 5.700 6.150 1.100
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
mget(letters[1:5]) %>%
  enframe %>%
  unnest(value) %>%
  group_by(grp = rowid(name)) %>% 
  summarise(value = mean(value)) %>%
  pull(value)
```

-output

```
[1] 2.720 5.175 5.700 6.150 1.100
```

Answer (score 3):

Interesting to see the wide range of timings on a larger list:

```
library(plyr)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)

set.seed(976933858)
l <- unname(split(runif(1e5), sample(1e4, 1e5, TRUE)))

f0 <- function(l) diff(c(0, cumsum(unlist(l)[order(sequence(lengths(l)))])[cumsum(lens <- rev(cumsum(rev(tabulate(lengths(l))))))]))/lens # jblood94
f1 <- function(l) sapply(transpose(l), mean, na.rm = TRUE) # Mael
f2 <- function(l) as.numeric(tapply(unlist(l), sequence(lengths(l)), mean)) # onyambu
f3 <- function(l) rowMeans(sapply(l, `length<-`, max(lengths(l))), na.rm = TRUE) # onyambu
f4 <- function(L) rowMeans(sapply(L, `[`, 1:max(lengths(L))), na.rm = TRUE) # G. Grothendieck
f5 <- function(mylist) {
  # benson23
  max_L <- max(lengths(mylist))
  rowMeans(sapply(mylist, function(x) c(x, rep(NA, max_L - length(x)))), na.rm = T)
}
f6 <- function(l) l %>% enframe %>% unnest(value) %>% group_by(grp = rowid(name)) %>% summarise(value = mean(value)) %>% pull(value) # akrun
f7 <- function(l) unname(colMeans(rbind.fill.matrix(sapply(l, t)), na.rm = TRUE)) # onyambu
f8 <- function(L) rowMeans(do.call("cbind", lapply(L, ts)), na.rm = TRUE) # G. Grothendieck

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  jblood94 = f0(l),
  Mael = f1(l),
  onyambu1 = f2(l),
  onyambu2 = f3(l),
  G.Grothendieck1 = f4(l),
  benson23 = f5(l),
  akrun = f6(l),
  onyambu3 = f7(l),
  G.Grothendieck2 = f8(l),
  check = "identical"
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>             expr      min        lq       mean    median        uq      max neval
#>         jblood94   1.0303   1.15555   1.544470   1.22690   1.32600   6.4604   100
#>             Mael   1.7522   1.88085   3.214797   1.98215   2.11660  85.0957   100
#>         onyambu1   2.4569   2.61115   4.030907   2.77880   2.94575  99.1389   100
#>         onyambu2   4.1092   4.64760   6.034596   4.91770   6.23725  21.6162   100
#>  G.Grothendieck1   4.7224   5.11220   6.485828   5.63770   7.08075  12.9853   100
#>         benson23  10.7711  12.03325  16.352950  16.06155  19.34285  32.2033   100
#>            akrun  13.8533  16.11800  18.376538  17.09465  20.45810  39.1432   100
#>         onyambu3 342.7180 410.80445 465.461878 451.92355 504.14595 800.1453   100
#>  G.Grothendieck2 465.0375 509.92070 565.463577 553.64825 607.95115 777.0444   100
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try `colMeans` with option `na.rm = TRUE` like below

```
L <- max(lengths(lst))
m <- matrix(nrow = L, ncol = L)
m[cbind(rep(seq_along(lst), lengths(lst)), sequence(lengths(lst)))] <- unlist(lst)
colMeans(m, na.rm = TRUE)
```

which gives

```
[1] 2.720 5.175 5.700 6.150 1.100
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, based on the idea that the matrix resulting from row binding `a, b, c, d, e` is *triangular*:

```r
m <- matrix(NA, 5, 5)
m[upper.tri(m, diag = T)] <- c(a, b, c, d, e)
colMeans(t(m), na.rm = T)

#> [1] 2.720 5.175 5.700 6.150 1.100
```